# Got error when trying to get value of a "checked input" using 2 or more times clicking on it in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project and need to get the value of the `checked input[type="radio"]` when clicking on the inputs.

This is my HTMl markup:

```
@if (Model.ProductColors.Any())
{
       <div class="fs-sm mb-4"><span class="text-heading fw-medium me-1">رنگ:</span><span class="text-muted" id="colorValue"></span></div>
       <div class="fs-sm mb-4"><span class="text-heading fw-medium me-1">کدرنگ:</span><span class="text-muted" id="colorCode"></span></div>
       <div class="checkBox position-relative me-n4 mb-3">
       @{int j = 1;
        }
       @foreach (var item in Model.ProductColors)
       {

            <div onclick="doActiveRadioButton('color_@j')" id="div_color_@j" class="productColor form-check form-option form-check-inline mb-2">
                  <input @((j==1)?"checked":"") class="test form-check-input" type="radio" name="color" id="color_@j" data-bs-label="colorOption" value="@item.ColorId">
                  <label class="form-option-label rounded-circle" for="color1"><span class="form-option-color rounded-circle" style="background-image: url(/Images/ProductThumbs/@item.ImageName)"></span></label>
            </div>

            j++;
        }
```

I've tried to get the value at the end of below codes:

```
<script>
    function doActiveRadioButton(id) {
            var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".productColor input");
            console.log(slides.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                slides[i].removeAttribute("checked");
            }
            var s = document.getElementById(id);
            s.setAttribute("checked", "checked");

            var g = document.querySelectorAll(".productColor label");
            for (var i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
                g[i].style.border = "1px solid #e3e9ef";
            }

            var d = document.querySelector("#div_" + id + " label");
            d.style.border = "1px solid #fe696a";

            var radioId = document.querySelector('.productColor input[type = "radio"]:checked');
            console.log(radioId);
            var c = document.querySelector("#colorCode");
            c.innerHTML = "green!";
            
        }
</script>
```

When I use `console.log()` to log the radioId, I mean the following part:

```
var radioId = document.querySelector('.productColor input[type = "radio"]:checked').value;
            console.log(radioId);
```

For the first time, it works correctly and showing me the true radioId (for example 9), but when I click on the input for the second time or more, it shows me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
> at doActiveRadioButton (2008:1621)
> at HTMLDivElement.onclick (2008:745)

Would anybody explain it to me and give me some sulotions or alternatives please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you look for the input that is checked. When it is checked you'll find it. When you uncheck it, it is no longer found and `document.querySelector` returns `null`. That means that the `value` property no longer exists.

You might want to make a check first if the element is found or not.

```
const productColorInput = document.querySelector('.productColor input[type="radio"]:checked')
if (productColorInput !== null) {
  const radioId = productColorInput.value;
  console.log(radioId);
}
```

Or check the `checked` property instead of querying a checked input. (This might be more solid as it always returns an element).

```
const productColorInput = document.querySelector('.productColor input[type="radio"]');
if (productColorInput.checked === true) {
  const radioId = productColorInput.value;
  console.log(radioId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if it returned null? I need it to return the value every time, not just once!

Comment: If it returned `null` then your element is not found. So I'd suggest that you use the 2nd code snippet where you evaluate if the element is clicked or not. But the question remains: what should the input return when it is unchecked?

Comment: See, it doesn't matter what the unchecked input shows! I just need the value of the checked input because by every click on it, I need the id of the color(clicked input) to send it to the server and then load the information of the clicked input(or clicked color) using ajax

Comment: And I didn't know whay it shows me "undefined" in console manager when I try to click on the input for 2 or more times!

Comment: Then all you have to do is to look for the input without the `:checked` part in the query and return the `value`. Because you don't want to select the input when it is checked, but on every occasion.

Comment: Yes, finally got it. your last comment solved my issue. But whay do I had to look for the input without `:checked` part? Would you please explain it to me briefly?

Comment: You can remove `:checked` from the selector.

Comment: @Hossein Because your checkbox is not always checked. Looking for a checked checkboxes will not return the `<input>` element when it is not checked. Without `:checked` you look for the `<input>` regardless if it has been checked or not, resulting in always getting the input if it is on the page.